# Taxonomy term permalink is not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have CPT called `forms_cpt` and a Taxonomy called `forms_tax`. In my `page-forms.php` I am able to crate a list of `forms_tax` terms like

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

which is creating a list of terms. but whenever I click on them it landed in a wrong URL. For example if click on `soccer` term it landed at

```
http://www.domain.ca/soccer/
```

instead of

```
http://www.domain.ca/Forms/soccer/
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
 function gen_forms_tax() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Form Types',
        'singular_name'              => 'Form Type',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Form Types',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Form Types',
        'parent_item'                => 'Form Parent',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Form Parents:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Form Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Form',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Form',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Form',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Form with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Form',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Form',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Form',
        'not_found'                  => 'Form Not Found',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'forms_tax', array( 'forms_cpt' ), $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'gen_forms_tax', 0 );
 
 

function gen_forms_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => 'Forms',
        'singular_name'       => 'Form',
        'menu_name'           => 'Form',
        'name_admin_bar'      => 'Form',
        'parent_item_colon'   => 'Form Parent:',
        'all_items'           => 'All Forms',
        'view_item'           => 'View Forms',
        'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Form',
        'add_new'             => 'Add New Form',
        'new_item'            => 'New Form',
        'edit_item'           => 'Edit Form',
        'update_item'         => 'Update Form',
        'search_items'        => 'Search Form',
        'not_found'           => 'Form Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Form Not found in Trash',
    );
    $args = array(
        'description'         => 'This Post Type Adds Form to Website',
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'excerpt', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'forms_tax' ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'Forms','with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => true ),
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'forms_cpt', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'gen_forms_cpt', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : You need to follow the steps given below.

```
1) Go to Settings from Admin panel.
2) Go to permalinks
3) Save the permalinks
```

It should work after you save the parmalinks. You always need update the permalinks once you add any rewrite rule to the site.